# Change default date of mysql

Tags: php, mysql

From last three days I used to the set the posted date of event e.t.c but automatically my server provide me one date back.

I also use default setting like :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

and use mysql code like :

```
$sql="insert  into event set event_name = '".trim(ucfirst($data['event_name']))."' ,
event_description = '".trim(ucfirst($data['event_description']))."' ,
event_posted_date = now() ;
mysql_query($sql);
```

But it save one date back.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: If you have a shared hosting it is probably because of the date and time set on the hosting machine

Answer (score 1):

Try to use date  from PHP insted of `NOW()`

```
 $today =date("Y-m-d H:is");
 $sql="insert  into event set event_name = '".trim(ucfirst($data['event_name']))."' ,
 event_description = '".trim(ucfirst($data['event_description']))."' ,
 event_posted_date = '$today' ";
```

**OR**

Find the file in your mysql server **mysql.conf**,check out the [default-time-zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).,Change to `Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: it is on server ont on local host

Comment: @user3840898 ,I think ,You should have the root access to the mysql server.

Comment: The reason was MySql server running on a different timezone,You change timezone for PHP only,Not for MySql.NOW() will return with mysql timezone

Comment: Do you have the permittion to edit the mysql config file?Is that a dedicated server or shared hosting server?

Comment: @user3840898 Try CONVERT_TZ() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 0):

execute  this mysql query before executing your query

```
$sql_set_time =  "SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

are you on localhost or any other web server ?

even if you set `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`

this function will show the date and time that set to Asia/Kolkata in your server.

may be date in your server set wrong(if on localhost, system time may be wrong).

Comment: ask your hosting provider to check whether date for timezone Asia/Kolkata correct or not(check it matches your local time and date).